# product detail page - move block to primary product container

Tags: layout, xml, product-view, page-layouts, ultimo

I would like to move the static block (a custom block from infortis ultimo theme) `block_product_secondary_bottom` to the `container_product_primary_1` container after `product.info.price`. How do I do that? thanks

below is part of the catalog_product_view.xml

```
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Infortis\Base\Block\Product\View" name="product-view-wrapper" template="product/view.phtml" before="-">
            <container name="container_product_image_1" label="Product View, Image Column" />
            <container name="container_product_primary_1" label="Product View, Primary Column, Container 1" />
            <container name="container_product_primary_2" label="Product View, Primary Column, Container 2" />
            <container name="container_product_secondary_1" label="Product View, Secondary Column, Container 1" />
            <container name="container_product_secondary_2" label="Product View, Secondary Column, Container 2" />
            <container name="container_product_lower_primary_1" label="Product View, Lower Primary Column, Container 1" />
            <container name="container_product_lower_primary_2" label="Product View, Lower Primary Column, Container 2" />
            <container name="container_product_lower_secondary_1" label="Product View, Lower Secondary Column, Container 1" />
            <container name="container_product_lower_secondary_2" label="Product View, Lower Secondary Column, Container 2" />
            <!-- Static blocks -->
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_product_secondary_bottom">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_product_secondary_bottom</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>

    <!-- Insert product view blocks into the new product view wrapper -->
    <move element="product.info.main" destination="product-view-wrapper" />
    <move element="product.info.media" destination="product-view-wrapper" />
    <move element="bundle.options.container" destination="product-view-wrapper" />
    <move element="product.info.details" destination="product-view-wrapper" />
    <move element="catalog.product.related" destination="product-view-wrapper" />
    <move element="product.info.upsell" destination="product-view-wrapper" />

    <!-- Move some blocks to new positions -->
    <!-- <move element="product.info.stock.sku" destination="product.info.price" after="product.price.final" /> -->
    <!-- <move element="product.info.social" destination="product.info.main" after="-" /> -->
    <move element="product.info.overview" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.price" />
    <move element="container_product_primary_1" destination="product.info.main" before="product.info.price" />
    <!-- <move element="container_product_primary_2" destination="product.info.main" after="-" /> -->

    <!-- Move some blocks outside the "product.info.main" to manipulate their position inside template file -->
    <move element="page.main.title" destination="product-view-wrapper" />
    <move element="product.info.review" destination="product-view-wrapper"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add below line in end of your file

```
<move element="block_product_secondary_bottom" destination="container_product_primary_1" after="product.info.price" />
```

Comment: thanks! Figured that out yesterday as well.

Answer (score 1):

you may try this.

```
<move element="block_product_secondary_bottom" destination="container_product_primary_1"  />
```